# fill the areas with different colors covered by latitude and longitude according to the analysis in the google map

Tags: google-maps, colors, latitude-longitude

I want to shade the area of latitude and longitude with different colors as the data differs in the google map?
Like for 10%, color will be lighter
for 20%, color will be more darker and so on.

Comment: First please tell me, can we give color to area covered by the lat and long in google  map?

Comment: I want to color the latlong bounds in google maps.